# Push batches of changes to main branch in Bazaar dotted notation

Tags: bazaar

I'm a DVCS newbie using Bazaar. I made a dev branch of the main repo and made many small commits. After I did a `bzr push`, the main line has sequential revision numbers (10,11,12,13) of all my small changes. How can I make it use dotted notation so the log isn't cluttered with a million insignificant commits? I want the main repo to store my changes as 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, etc. (or whatever the dotted notation style is).

TL;DR: I want the main branch to only show a commit message summary for a batch of smaller changes made in a separate branch, and store those changes in dotted notation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge your feature branches in, rather than pushing/pulling them in. If you want revisions 10, 11, 12 and 13 to be "grouped" (be considered a feature branch), do something like this:

```
bzr branch -r9 YOURTRUNK temp
cd temp
bzr merge -d temp YOURTRUNK
bzr ci -m "Merge feature X"
bzr push --overwrite ../YOURTRUNK
```